# Javascript command for pausing movie stream?

Tags: javascript

I need a Javascript command that pauses video stream embeded from Putlocker as soon as specific DIV pops up.

Here is an example that works with JWPlayer

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
 if (document.getElementById("gw-node-overlay"){ 
      jwplayer().stop(); 
      clearInterval(interval);
 }}, 1000);
```

Edit:
Video is iframed. Example: `<iframe src="http://www.putlocker.com/embed/#####" width="700" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

Comment: To be totally clear, is it a `<video>` or an `<embed>`?

Comment: If it's a Flash-based player you'll have to find the docs on that particular player. There is no universal JS call to do this.